# Dynamically creating a Jira issue using jira-connector nodejs module

Tags: node.js, jira-rest-api

I am using the **jira-connector** nodejs module to create a JIRA ticket dynamically:

```
/**
 * Creates a JIRA Issue
 * @param {*} jira The jira client.
 * @param {string} summary The summary of the ticket.
 */
function createIssueInJira(jira, issueSummary) {
  console.log(`Creating JIRA Release Readiness ticket for ${issueSummary}...`)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jira.issue.createIssue({
        issue: { fields: { project: { id: '11111' }, summary: issueSummary, issuetype: { id: '22222' } }}
    }, (error, issue) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

It keeps failing with the following error:

```
{ errorMessages: [ 'Internal server error' ], errors: {} }
(node:48381) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]
(node:48381) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: just needed to remove the `issue:` object.

```
/**
     * Creates a JIRA Issue
     * @param {*} jira The jira client.
     * @param {string} summary The summary of the ticket.
     */
    function createIssueInJira(jira, issueSummary) {
      console.log(`Creating JIRA Release Readiness ticket for ${issueSummary}...`)
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jira.issue.createIssue({
            fields: { project: { id: '11111' }, summary: issueSummary, issuetype: { id: '22222' } 
        },
        (error, issue) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return reject(error);
          }
        });
      });
    }
```